# how to split multipage tiff into smaller multipage tiff in C#

Tags: c#, tiff

i have a 6-page-tiff image file.
i need to split it into 3 tiff files, each of them has 2 pages.

original tiff : p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6

result:
tiff1: p1 p2
tiff2: p3 p4
tiff3: p5 p6

how can i do that in C#?

Comment: take the count and loop with 2 count

Comment: what is 'tiff'?

Comment: my problem is not about reaching the correct index, but about splitting..  
i have a code that splits the tif into seperate files by saving each single page... but now i need to split into files that has multiple pages